# In Java how to read a file from network directory (windows mount directory)

Tags: java, io

in my windows pc, I have a mounted network directory called  p:/projects/file.txt

I got a file not found exception when I did this "File f = new File(p:/projects/file.txt)"

I thought the Java I/O 's native implementation has a hook with windows.

but apparently its not, is there anyway doing it?

Comment: If the drive is mounted it should work. Permissions? Correct path? Try reading something on c to check your code is ok. And should those be backslashes?

Comment: Strange, that should work...are you sure that the case is correct (e.g. it's not e.g. File.txt)?

Comment: It should work as the OP wrote it, and there's no need to use backslashes. Getting the case correct would not normally matter in Java on Windows, but if the network mount is to a Linux filesystem (for example) then Piskvor is right: you will need to get the case correct.

Comment: Your mounted network directory is called `p:/projects/file.txt`?  Or some network directory has been mapped to the drive letter `P`?  The exact code you give wouldn't compile, it has invalid syntax.  You need to give an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) (I know we won't have access to your mounted directory but if you give real code we might be able to help you out).

Comment: the real code I used is "File f = new File(C:\files\test.txt)"  and the network mounted drive is in "P:/projects/file.txt", the code works with local drive, not with the P drive

Comment: answer to my own question: I forgot the to capitalize the driver letter P:/..... , the p:/ surely did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the real code I used is "File f = new File(C:\files\test.txt)" and the network mounted drive is in "P:/projects/file.txt", the code works with local drive, not with the P drive

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but you realize you've got forward slashes for your P: Drive and back slashes for your C: Drive. Forward slashes don't work on Windows. They do on a linux or Unix system.